# how can i iterate from a list to output value?

Tags: terraform

I m getting from terraform  12, call a list of values

```
data "oci_core_instances" "test_instances" {
    #Required
    compartment_id = "${var.compartment_ocid}"

    availability_domain = "${data.oci_identity_availability_domains.ads.availability_domains[0].name}"
}

// numInstances = 3 for my case 
locals {
  numInstances = length(data.oci_core_instances.test_instances.instances)
}
```

and i want to iterate like (pseudo code) :

```
# Output the result single element
output "format_instances_name_state" {
         value = "${
           for (i=0 ; i< 3; i++)
           format("%s=>%s",data.oci_core_instances.test_instances.instances[i].display_name,data.oci_core_instances.test_instances.instances[i].state)
           } " 
}
```

how can i do this in terraform ?

i have tried this :

```
# Output the result single element
output "format_instances_name_state" {
         value = "${
           for i in local.numInstances :
           format("%s=>%s",data.oci_core_instances.test_instances.instances[i].display_name,data.oci_core_instances.test_instances.instances[i].state)
           } " 
}
```

but i m getting this error:

```
Error: Extra characters after interpolation expression

  on main.tf line 64, in output "format_instances_state_element_single":
  63:
  64:            for i in local.numInstances :

Expected a closing brace to end the interpolation expression, but found extra
characters.
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you really want here is a map from display name to state, in which case the following expression would produce that:

```
output "instance_states" {
  value = {
    for inst in data.oci_core_instances.test_instances.instances : inst.display_name => inst.state
  }
}
```

If you really do need that list of strings with `=>` inside for some reason, you can adapt the above to get it, like this:

```
output "format_instances_state_element_single" {
  value = [
    for inst in data.oci_core_instances.test_instances.instances : "${inst.display_name}=>${inst.state}"
  ]
}
```

In this second case the `for` expression is marked by `[ ]` brackets instead of `{ }` braces, which means it will produce a list result rather than a map result.

Comment: How can you add a description alongside the value, but have part of the description depend on the current element as well?

Comment: Hi @TheEdgeOfRage! If you have a follow-up question then I suggest starting a new top-level question for it, so that you can share a fuller description of what you intend to achieve and what you tried already.